# How would I use variable of another function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a remover of an element(`p` tag in more specific) that will be created by user. In my page user can write information in the page through a form and also there will be a delete button by which they can delete the element they have wrote on the page. Here is the code snippet

```js
function writedesc() {
  var x = document.getElementById("testinput").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("desc").value;

  var para = document.createElement("P");
  var text = document.createTextNode(x);
  para.appendChild(text);

  var area = document.getElementById("wtf");
  wtf.appendChild(para);
  para.style.marginLeft = "20px";
  para.style.marginTop = "20px";

  var para2 = document.createElement("P");
  var text = document.createTextNode(y);
  para2.appendChild(text);

  var area = document.getElementById("wtf");
  wtf.appendChild(para2);
  para2.style.marginLeft = "20px";
  para2.style.marginTop = "20px";


}

function remove() {
  // I want to remove the first para here
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Cool HTML DOM</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="testinput" placeholder="product name">
  <input type="text" id="desc" placeholder="more about it">
  <button onclick="writedesc()">Click Here</button>
  <div id="wtf"></div>
  <button onclick="remove()">Remove first child</button>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Now I have to write the could in the function `remove()` which will remove my first element which has been stored into `para` variable. For that anyhow I have to access the `para` variable from `remove()` function. How would I access that `para` variable from the `remove()` function?? `

Comment: You would need to take the variable out of the function and make it global

Comment: define `var para` in a global space which common for both functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give the `<p>` tag an id, you can delete it without having to access the the variable `para` and so avoid using globals.

```
function writedesc() {
  var x = document.getElementById("testinput").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("desc").value;

  var para = document.createElement("P");
  para.id = "para1";
  var text = document.createTextNode(x);
  para.appendChild(text);

  var area = document.getElementById("wtf");
  wtf.appendChild(para);
  para.style.marginLeft = "20px";
  para.style.marginTop = "20px";

  var para2 = document.createElement("P");
  para2.id = "para2";
  var text = document.createTextNode(y);
  para2.appendChild(text);

  var area = document.getElementById("wtf");
  wtf.appendChild(para2);
  para2.style.marginLeft = "20px";
  para2.style.marginTop = "20px";
}

function remove() {
    var para1 = document.getElementById("para1");
    if (para1){
        para1.parentNode.removeChild(para1)
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, actually I was thinking about giving an id to my paragraph but I thought its not possbile. thanks for help, that was really in the point.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x;

function first(){

  x = 8;
}

function second(){
  x = 2; 
}
```

both the above two functions are accessing same `x` variable

Comment: Nice explanation withing fewest words. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use global variables , you can access this variables in any function

```js
var x;
var y;

var para;
var text;

var para2;
var text2;

function writedesc() {

  x = document.getElementById("testinput").value;
  y = document.getElementById("desc").value;

  para = document.createElement("P");
  text = document.createTextNode(x);

  para2 = document.createElement("P");
  text2 = document.createTextNode(y);

  para.appendChild(text);

  var area = document.getElementById("wtf");
  wtf.appendChild(para);
  para.style.marginLeft = "20px";
  para.style.marginTop = "20px";

  
  para2.appendChild(text2);

  var area = document.getElementById("wtf");
  wtf.appendChild(para2);
  para2.style.marginLeft = "20px";
  para2.style.marginTop = "20px";


}

function remove() {
  // I want to remove the first para here
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Cool HTML DOM</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="testinput" placeholder="product name">
  <input type="text" id="desc" placeholder="more about it">
  <button onclick="writedesc()">Click Here</button>
  <div id="wtf"></div>
  <button onclick="remove()">Remove first child</button>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was help full

Answer (score 0):

Define a global variable g object and store variables as key

```
var g = {para : "", para2 : ""};

// to access para, use
function printParas() {
console.log(g.para);
console.log(g.para2);

}

function addSomeContent1() {
g.para = "First Random Content for para1";
g.para2 = "First Random Content for para2";
printParas();
}

function addSomeContent2() {
g.para = "Second Random Content for para1";
g.para2 = "Second Random Content for para2";
printParas();
}

function removeContent() {
g.para = "";
g.para2 = "";
printParas();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I've learned a good and new concept from your answer.